# Django: How to get tax amount for diffrent countries and multiply it by product price in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am creating an ecommerce system where i would need to calculate taxes for diffrent countries during checkout. I have added a flat rate for the tax, but that is not how tax works, it need to be percentage based which i have done, but how do i know the country a user is about to order a product from and also get the tax amount for that country and do my basic calculation.

please if you have done this before i would really appreciate any help as that would help me fix this issue.

Right now, this is how i am performing the tax calculation with a fixed percentage for all users from all countries

```
 new_tax_amount = 0
 tax_amount_by_percentage = 25 / 100 # 25% / 100 = 0.25
 new_tax_amount += int(item['qty']) * float(tax_amount_by_percentage )
```

This works well for me, but i need to know how to get tax percentage based on the country the user is trying to order the product from

Answer (score 1):

So first we need to know from where the user is logging in for that you can read the official Django documentation which describes in detail about how to use [GEOIP2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/gis/geoip2/)!

For the second part of your problem the best solution that I can think of is to create an array of all the countries and their respective tax brackets for your product.

Start with the most popular 50 countries first.
Good Luck !!!!

Comment: thanks for your response, how about for the guest checkout where the user does not need to login, how do i determine thier country?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).